# Как подключить bootstrap без изменения глобальных стилей? Web

Tags: css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Я сверстал одностраничник ручками. Теперь, допустим, я хочу подключить bootstrap - это не сложно. Однако проблема в том, что при подключении bootstrap.css изменяются также и глобальные стили - об этом даже в документации говорится. Так, например, все заголовки h2 меняют шрифт и толщину и размер шрифта. Из-за этого сверстанная до подключения страничка выглядит не так, как должна. Переопределять все эти стили вручную - та еще морока.

Есть ли способ подключить bootstrap без изменения глобальных стилей?

Comment: Скорее нет, потому что bootstrap - это фреймворк, чтобы на нем что-то делали, а не накидывали поверху чего-то... Плюс там много `!important`, что в принципе слишком усложняет жизнь...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar есть ли тогда наборы готовых компонентов и/или стилей, которые можно выборочно использовать на сайте?

Answer (score 2):

Скачайте [исходники](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/) и в файле `scss/bootstrap.scss` удалите ненужное.

```
// Configuration
@import "functions";
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "utilities";

// Layout & components
@import "root";
@import "reboot"; // <- Сброс стилей
@import "type";
@import "images";
@import "containers";
@import "grid";
@import "tables";
@import "forms";
@import "buttons";
@import "transitions";
@import "dropdown";
@import "button-group";
@import "nav";
@import "navbar";
@import "card";
@import "accordion";
@import "breadcrumb";
@import "pagination";
@import "badge";
@import "alert";
@import "progress";
@import "list-group";
@import "close";
@import "toasts";
@import "modal";
@import "tooltip";
@import "popover";
@import "carousel";
@import "spinners";
@import "offcanvas";

// Helpers
@import "helpers";

// Utilities
@import "utilities/api";
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможен вариант с тем,  чтобы повысить специфичность самого bootstrap. Для этого можно обернуть весь код bootstrap-a в какой-нибудь класс.  Для этого можно использовать less или scss препроцессоры.

1. Сделать новый файл .less
2. Сделать класс и вставить внутрь код bootstrap
3. После,  конвертировать в .css, если не используются препроцессоры

   .className {
   ... код бутстрапа
   }

После этого можно будет сделать блок с классом className, а внутри можно будет использовать классы bootstrap.

P.S. Вариант крайне костыльный, но однажды применялся на практике.  Легче писать сразу используя bootstrap или другую библиотеку. Или писать без них используя свои стили.

Comment: А почему просто не собрать из исходников как душа пожелает?

Comment: @nazarpunk Скорее всего то, что будет взято из пересобранного бутстрапа все равно переопределит часть уже написанного css. А так будет гарантия, что старая верстка останется целой и не будет сломана.

Comment: А что мешает при сборке не специфичности добавить, а префикс. Будет же удобней и возможно быстрее.

Comment: В целом тоже вариант. Сам уже несколько лет не пишу на бутстрапах и подобном. Можешь добавить в свой ответ, тогда он будет еще круче.