# Bootstrap классы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Мне нужно чтобы все классы Bootstrap 5 в html коде начинались с тега перед их названием, например: ".`bs_`link-info" ".`bs_`d-inline". Возможно ли это?

Comment: Конечно возможно, скачиваете исходники и переименовываете.

Comment: Тут уже упоминались способы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1330094